# string.ascii_lowercase[2:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:2]

Tags: python

I am new to Python and try to play python challenge. And in the level 2, the code is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe3uk.png)
I don't understand what does `string.ascii_lowercase[2:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:2]` means. Also I cannot find it in official document.

Comment: you should try to execute it. You'll see it just puts the 2 first alphabet letters in the end.

Comment: Yes I execute it and I know how it looks like in the result. I just don't know how this sentence achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's best explained when the steps are done seperatly:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

>>> string.ascii_lowercase[:2]  # Take the first two items from the string
'ab'

>>> string.ascii_lowercase[2:]  # Take everything starting by the third item
'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

>>> string.ascii_lowercase[2:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:2]  # concatenate them
'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab'
```

This is explained in the [official Python tutorial (in the strings section)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Xueyuan No problem. Please don't forget to accept (and/or upvote) the answer. :)